# Batch file - How to search in Google search and open specific web site

Tags: batch-file, variables

can you tell me please is it possible to make a batch file which search a word in Google, and after that opens a specific web site from Google search page. So I think that it needs to click on search result. 
It can be a first result from search page.

my code at this moment:

```
@echo off
set executecounter=0
:loop
start chrome --user-data-dir="C:\Users\(username)\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"--new-window --window-position=1280,0 --window-size=10,10 "https://www.google.com/search?q=%*"
timeout /t 20
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T > nul
set /a executecounter=%executecounter%+1
if "%executecounter%"=="180" goto done
goto loop
:done
echo Complete!
pause
```

Thank you

Comment: the easiest way will be with [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/)

Answer (score 0):

I did a very simple experiment: I searched for "Tralala" on the Google Chrome address bar, and the URL became a more complicated version than this:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=Tralala
```

In order to launch Google Chrome, I need to go to directory "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\".

So by combining both, I get the following commands:

```
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application"
Chrome https://www.google.com/search?q=Tralala
```

You can use this as an input to create your batchfile

Comment: but this is not what i need :(